# Windows 2003 SBS licensing

Tags: windows-server-2003, exchange, licensing, windows-sbs-2003

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can you help me with my software licensing question?](https://serverfault.com/questions/215405/can-you-help-me-with-my-software-licensing-question)

I've Windows 2003 SBS and 40 CAL licenses for SBS. I also have Microsoft Exchange 2007 license for 2nd server which acts as front-end for Exchange (outbound/inbound emails come thru it and OWA works on it).

Does it require separate CAL's for Exchange 2007 even thou SBS has all mailboxes etc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> STANDARD LICENSING DISCLAIMER:
>
> While SF can give you a decent idea, and more often than not a very good answer, the best place to ask these types of questions is to ask you licensing representative from Microsoft.

If i'm remembering my conversation with our rep a year ago or so, the answer is no you don't need 2x the cals.